# Can multiple domains point to the same Azure web app?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, domain-name

I'm using Azure for my website and I have 2 domain names that I would like to use for the same site.

For example, I want these 2 domains `www.abc.com` and `www.abc.asia` to be the same website (not redirected). Such that `www.abc.com/contactus` and `www.abc.asia/contactus` will be the same page.

Comment: website on Azure, host on Azure VM or azure web app?

Comment: It's Azure Web App

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, this is possible (and easy to do). I did the following:

1. Buy two separate domains.
2. Configure the DNS A and TXT records of both domains to point to my Azure web app.
3. On the **Custom domains** blade, clicked **Add hostname** to add each domain name.

Both domain names now point to the same Azure web app.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using Azure for my website and I have 2 domain names that I would
>   like to use for the same site.
>
> For example, I have these 2 domains www.abc.com and www.abc.asia to be
>   the same website (not redirected).

Yes, as far as I know, we **can** map two domain names to one web site, same as on-premise.

Comment: @KaiyanLeong Azure DNS is not the domain registrar, so you should buy two domain names, then add `CNAME` to map two domain names to the website.

Comment: Shouldn't it be the A record? So currently whether I type .asia or .com it works in getting to the /sub that I want, but it always reverts to .com

Comment: you are right, if you want to map those domain names to webapp's public IP address, we can use A record. `but it always reverts to .com`, do you mean you want to browse www.abc.asia/sub, then the url reverts to www.abc.com/sub? it may effect by DNS cache, for test, you can use two PCs to browse this website.

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.